# How to divide numbers from a string into two lists according to what operator(+ or -) preceds them?

Tags: string, list, operators

```
string = "6+324-909+5+55-1"

listPositive = []
listNegative = []
```

I would like to put numbers with "+" in front of them in listPositive and numbers with "-" in front of them in listNegative. Just the numbers without operators, but using the operators for distinction. I have managed to find a way to seperate the first number which has neither plus nor minus in front of it.

I am very very green and I will gladly hear about different ways to go about it or even suggestions for a whole different line of thinking.

I tried:

```
s1='678-6783742+2342+4-8'
lst=s1.split()
sample=[]
for i in lst:
    if '-' in i:
        sample.append(i[1:])
print(sample)
```

And was expecting:

```
['6783742', '8']
```

But it only worked that way when I put spaces in like this:

```
s1='678 -6783742 +2342 +4 -8'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you already have the answer: replace`-` with  `-` and `+` with  `+` (note the space before operator) and then split:

```py
s = "678-6783742+2342+4-8"
s = s.replace("+", " +").replace("-", " -")

negative = []

for i in s.split():
    if i.startswith("-"):
        negative.append(i[1:])

print(negative)
```

Prints:

```
['6783742', '8']
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrej. Interesting. Would that be considered an "elegant" solution?

Comment: @OndrášŠponer Well, depends. If it works then it works. I would do it with regex (`re` module, but thats difficult topic for beginner).

Comment: Okay, thank for taking my skills into consideration. Have a good one!